# Recursive depth first search python that returns weighted total

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

I am trying to write a depth first search function in python. I am having trouble returning the total weight of the shortest path. This is what I have so far..

```
def dfs(road,start,end,dist_so_far,path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        path.append(path)
        del path[-1]
        print(path)
    for node, weight in roads[start]:
        if node not in path:
            dfs(roads, node, end, dist_so_far, path)
    return #return total weight
```

I am lost at the moment, any ideas on what I need to do? The inputs look like:

```
road = {'f': [('d', 2.0), ('g', 7.0)], 
        'b': [('a', 5.0), ('d', 6.0)], 
        'c': [('a', 8.0), ('d', 2.0)], 
        'e': [('d', 12.0), ('g', 3.0)], 
        'g': [('e', 3.0), ('f', 7.0)], 
        'a': [('b', 5.0), ('c', 8.0)], 
        'd': [('b', 6.0), ('c', 2.0), ('e', 12.0), ('f', 2.0)]}

print(dfs(road, 'a', 'b', 0.0))
```

I need the function to return total shortest distance. I'm still relatively new to python and what I have already could be completely wrong.

**EDIT** I think I figured it out, I was kinda going about it wrong..

```
def dfs(place, dist_so_far, roads, distances):
    if (place not in distances) or (distances[place] > dist_so_far):
        distances[place] = dist_so_far
        for combo in roads[place]:
            to_city, dist = combo
            dfs(to_city, dist_so_far+dist, roads, distances)

distances = { }
start_place = 'a'
dfs(start_place, 0.0, roads, distances )

if destination in distances :
    print("Distance from {} to {} is {}".format(start_place,destination, distances[destination]))
```

Hopefully this helps someone else later on down the road.

Comment: You know that DFS cannot return the shortest path in a weighted graph, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFS doesn't return the shortest path in a weighted graph and also for a simple, undirected graph doesn't always gives the BEST answer and you need to use BFS in that case. Imagine the following graph:

```
1
| \
2--3
```

In this graph there is a loop and if you use DFS to find the shortest path from 1 to 3 you'll get `1-2-3` with length of 2 while we can go from 1 to 3 directly, but if you use BFS you'll get the correct result.

Back to your question, in a weighted graph you can use `Dijkstra or Bellman–Ford or Floyed` depending on what you need or what type of graph you have. Anyway, if you want to find one of the paths from `a->b` using DFS you can use a global variable to store distance and finish the algorithm after finding the first path like this:

```
res, found = 0, False
def dfs(roads,start,end,dist_so_far,path=[]):
    global res, found
    if found: return

    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        path.append(path)
        del path[-1]
        print(path)
        res = dist_so_far
        found = True
        return

    for node, weight in roads[start]:
        if node not in path:
            dfs(roads, node, end, dist_so_far+weight, path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured it out. This is what I needed.